# How can I make this query sargable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to retrieve rows from my table with out a field starting with a certain value:

I'm currently doing so with a simple query like this:

```
SELECT A.ID FROM SCHEMA.TABLE A WHERE A.FIELD NOT LIKE 'WORD%'
```

However, I have learned that `A.FIELD` sometimes contains a varying number of blank spaces before "WORD".

Obviously, I could re-write the query with another wildcard, but that would make it non-sargable and slow it down a fair bit (this query runs on a reasonably large table and needs to be as efficient as possible).

Is there any way I can write a sargable query to fix this problem?

Comment: Easy solution, sanitize your data and get rid of the leading spaces.  SQL doesn't care about trailing spaces but leading spaces definitely count.

Comment: I'm with @KrisGruttemeyer on cleansing the data. However, can you just trim the column? LTRIM(A.Field)

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer I've actually already done that, but I was curious  as to whether there was a way I could re-write the query in case I wouldn't have been able to clean the data for whatever reason.

Comment: Is it using index with the Like operator? AFAIK there is no index usage the instant you use the like operator, Am I wrong? (this is a trully doubt ok)

Comment: @JorgeCampos using LIKE does NOT automatically mean no indexes can be used. If you don't have a leading wildcard indexes can absolutely be utilized. It is when using a leading wildcard that there is no ability for the indexes to be used or helpful.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yup, you are wrong. In this case it *can* use an index since it doesn't have a wildcard at the beggining

Comment: It can still use the index as long as the wildcard operator is only at the end.  You may not get a screaming fast seek but it will at least be able to use it.  Think about a phone book, even if you only have the first 5 characters of someones last name, you can narrow down the results that much further.

Comment: How about adding a computed column that TRIMs the column and adding an index on that?

Comment: Thanks guys! Thats a good new knowledge!! I didn't knew about the leading wildcard!! Very good piece of information!! @SeanLange -lamak -krisgruttemeyer

Comment: @DavidG That would work too ( although it's not as easy as just cleaning the data).

Comment: @Mansfield Indeed, but it's not always possible to ensure that data is inserted cleanly.

Answer (score 6):

If you can't clean the data for any reason, one option is to add a computed column to your table that trims all leading and trailing spaces:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
    ADD TrimmedYourColumn as (RTRIM(LTRIM(YourColumn)))
```

And index the computed column:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_YourTable_TrimmedYourColumn 
    ON YourTable (TrimmedYourColumn)
```

And now search that column instead:

```
SELECT A.ID FROM YourTable A WHERE TrimmedYourColumn NOT LIKE 'WORD%'
```

Comment: In SQL Server  there is no `TRIM` function you need use `LTRIM(RTRIM(YourColumn))` instead.

Comment: @lad2025 Of course, I should have remembered that one!

Answer (score -4):

How about ltrim?

```
SELECT A.ID FROM SCHEMA.TABLE A WHERE ltrim(A.FIELD) NOT LIKE 'WORD%'
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't match with the `Is there any way I can write a sargable query to fix this problem?` requirement

Comment: I see your wanting to make sure indexes are used. I think you would have to clean the data. SQL is still fast. You may find that index or not, your query will run in a timely manner.